# PHP - mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Invalid argument in file

Tags: mysql, php

On a work project, I'm load-testing a php service on MySQL 5.6 loaded on a beefy Google Compute Engine VM.  After I exceed a certain amount of requests per second in my load test, MySQL starts giving me errors like:

```
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Invalid argument in
```

I've confirmed that we're passing the same arguments to `mysqli real_connect` both before and after those warnings start where the connection fails.

On the VM - memory & cpu have very low usage, we're not hitting limits in write iOPS ( our loadtest is write heavy ) and none of the charts on PMM are revealing anything that's going wrong at that time.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Let's see the arguments.  Or let's see a code snippet that includes the connect.

Comment: This question should ideally be asked on https://stackoverflow.com/, this question is not totally databases related.